# PHP not creating zip file

Tags: ajax, wordpress, zip

I am trying to create a function where the a user selects acf images, creates a zip file then sends this to an email but my the code doesn't create the zip file. I tried to check the zip->close() and this returns a false value. I also tried this without using ajax and it works! Not sure why it doesn't work when used as a function. Please check the code below.

```
$ret = array(
    'is_error' => false,
    'msg' => array(),
);


if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $ret['is_error'] = true;
     $ret['msg'][] = 'Email address is a required field';
}

if ($ret['is_error'] == false) {
    unset($_POST['action']);

    $images = $_POST['files']; 

    if( $images ){

        $destination = 'wp-content/uploads/downloads/' .time() . '.zip';

        if ( file_exists( $destination ) ){
            $ret['msg'][] = 'zip file exists';
        } 
        else {

            // If the file doesn't already exist, create the file
            $files = array();
            foreach( $images as $singlefile ) {
                // create an array of the image files in the gallery
                $files[] = get_attached_file( $singlefile );

            }
            
            if( count( $files ) ) {


                //Create a zip file in the location specified
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $zip->open( $destination, ZipArchive::CREATE );
                
                foreach( $files as $file ) {
                    
                    if ( file_exists($file) ) {
                        // if the file actually exists, add it to the zip file
                        $new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
                        $zip->addFile( $file, $new_filename );

                        
                    }else{
                        $ret['msg'][] = $file;

                        $ret['msg'][] = 'Not added';
                    }
                }

                $zip->close();

                readfile($destination);

                $ret['msg'][] = $zip->close();


                if(file_exists($destination)){  
                    ob_clean();
                    ob_end_flush();


                $protocols = array('https://', 'http://', 'https://www.', 'http://www.', 'www.');
                $siteURL =  str_replace($protocols, '', get_bloginfo('wpurl'));
                    
                $headers = 'From: '.get_bloginfo('name').' <noreply@'.$siteURL.'>';
                $to = $_POST['email'];
                $subject = "test";
                $body = "test";
                $attachments = array( $destination );

                wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments );

                unlink($destination);  


                $ret['msg'][] = 'Files sent. Please check your email';

                
                }else{
                    $ret['msg'][] = 'Files does not exist';
                }

            } else {
                // No images are found
                $ret['msg'][] = 'No files found';
            }
        }

    }
    
}

echo json_encode($ret);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code -

```
    # create new zip object
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    # create a temp file & open it
    $tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
    $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    # loop through each file
    foreach ($FILES_ARRAY as $file) {
     # download file
     $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
     #add it to the zip
     $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
    }
    # close zip
    $zip->close();

    # send the file to the browser as a download
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=image-pack-' . $post_id . '.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    readfile($tmp_file);
    unlink($tmp_file);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works! I only tweaked the $tmp_file = tempnam('.', ''); into $tmp_file = time() . '.zip'; for it to be a zip file.